# How livedata send the data to activity if any changes

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi I am reading this example of `LiveData` and `Observer` https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-android-architecture--cms-28749

MainActivityViewModel.kt

```
class MainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var notes: MutableLiveData<List<String>>? = null    
    fun getNotes(): LiveData<List<String>> {
        if (notes == null) {
            notes = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
            loadNotes()
        }
        return notes!!
    }
    private fun loadNotes() {
        // do async operation to fetch notes
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : LifecycleActivity(), AnkoLogger {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)
                .get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.getNotes().observe(
                this, Observer { 
                    notes -> info("notes: $notes")
                }
        )
    }
}
```

How `LiveData` is sending data to `MainActivity` if there is any changes in notes (new or delete). I see activity is calling `viewModel.getNotes()` which may not get called once onCreate method finish.

Comment: what do you mean by: `"which may not get called"`?

Comment: @pskink I mean onCreate doesn't get called after once, it get called once then if there is any change in the data after oncreate is called then how activity get notification of it ?

Comment: so your activity is visible on the screen but you say `onCreate` was not called?

Comment: `onCreate` is called only once. I mean after it is called if I create new note then how activity get information of newly inserted note

Comment: because you called `observe()` method with `android.arch.lifecycle.Observer` and its `onChanged()` method is called each time the data is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LiveData` isn't sending anything to `MainActivity`, it's "sending" to the `Observer` passed to the `observe` method. This `Observer` has a reference to `MainActivity` where it was created and can call its methods.

Comment: so if I create new note then will it get passed to activity own ? or do i need to do anything ?

Comment: You need not just to add to the `List`, but call `postValue` or `setValue` on the `LiveData` afterwards (see docs for the difference).